# Transaction with no result

Tags: express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am using Bluebird Promise, I am trying to do a transaction, save user record, then use userId to insert new record into room table:

```
var promise = new Promise(
    function resolver(resolve, reject) {
        bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
            User.forge(data)
            .save(null, { transacting: t })
            .then(function (user){
                Room.forge({ userId: user.id })
                .save(null, { transacting: t });
            })
        })
        .then(function (account) {
            resolve(account);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    });

return promise;
```

But I am not getting any successful or error response back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return a promise from the callback.

```
bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    return User.forge(data) // here
    .save(null, { transacting: t })
    .then(function (user){
        Room.forge({ userId: user.id })
        .save(null, { transacting: t });
    })
})
```